# SQLAlchemy JSON column - how to perform a contains query

Tags: python, mysql, json, sqlalchemy

I have the following table in mysql(5.7.12):

```
class Story(db.Model):
    sections_ids = Column(JSON, nullable=False, default=[])
```

*sections_ids* is basicly a list of integers [1, 2, ...,n].
I need to get all rows where sections_ids contains X.
I tried the following:

```
stories = session.query(Story).filter(
        X in Story.sections_ids
    ).all()
```

but it throws:

```
NotImplementedError: Operator 'contains' is not supported on this expression
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`JSON_CONTAINS(json_doc, val[, path])`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains):

```
from sqlalchemy import func

# JSON_CONTAINS returns 0 or 1, not found or found. Not sure if MySQL
# likes integer values in WHERE, added == 1 just to be safe
session.query(Story).filter(func.json_contains(Story.section_ids, X) == 1).all()
```

As you're searching an array at the top level, you do not need to give *path*. Alternatively beginning from 8.0.17 you can use [`value MEMBER OF(json_array)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_member-of), but using it in SQLAlchemy is a little less ergonomic in my opinion:

```
from sqlalchemy import literal

# self_group forces generation of parenthesis that the syntax requires
session.query(Story).filter(literal(X).bool_op('MEMBER OF')(Story.section_ids.self_group())).all()
```

Comment: You can read about generic functions in SQLA [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html).

Comment: Are you sure thats the right syntax? its not working for me... no error is raised... it just not continue to the next line...

Comment: Should be str(X)... (in my case X was int and only when casting to string it worked). THANKS!

Comment: I want to do the searching at 2nd level, how to specify the path?

Comment: @toufeeq Pass it as the 3rd argument.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I mean to ask, how to pass the wildcard path $[*].some_field. Since * is not allowed in sqlalchemy query

Comment: It is MySQL that does not allow a wildcard in a json path with [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains). Instead you could search for an object with the required key-value pair: `func.json_contains(Foo.bar, func.json_object("some_field", "some_value"))`.

Answer (score 17):

For whoever get here, but is using PostgreSQL instead:
your fields should be of the type `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB` (and not sqlalchemy_utils.JSONType) -

Then you can use the [`Comparator`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON.Comparator) object that is associated with the field with its `contains` (and others) operators.

Example:

```
Query(Mymodel).filter(MyModel.managers.comparator.contains(["user@gmail.com"]))
```

(note that the contained part must be a JSON fragment, not just a string)

Comment: `MyModel.managers` in this case is the column name ("managers"), not some special keyword.

Comment: If the contained part must be a JSON fragment, shouldn't the example be `...contains(['"user@gmail.com"'])`?