# SQLalchemy Json-configured varchar: how to filter

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I am using MySQL 8.0 and SQLalchemy.

I have a model as follows:

```
class Json(TypeDecorator):
    impl = String(1000)

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return json.dumps(value)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if not value:
            return None
        return json.loads(value)

class BookCommerce(Base):
    bcDetails = Column(Json)
```

This is rendered as varchar(1000) in the database, and the decorator means it all works well for accessing dict values that I save or retrieve from that field.

My problem is that I now want to search the field looking for values (including value fragments expressed as `%my_string%`). A query like this yields nothing:

```
BookCommerce.query.filter(BookCommerce.bcDetails.like(fragname))).all()
```

since SQLA (I think) renders the varchar into a JSON document before executing the query.
Strangely, the SQL resulting from this query does actually work in a MySQL command window.

I've tried the accepted solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470239/sqlalchemy-json-column-how-to-preform-a-contains-query#39470478) question, but it refers to the JSON type in MySQL and therefore croaks on the syntax (in Python and MySQL command line).

Any suggestions for how to handle this properly? I don't want to move away from this Json-decorated solution in general, I simply want a free-form search to locate matching records.

SQL queries obtained from echo=True on create_engine:

```
2021-03-25 19:47:11,638 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT bookcommerce.`bcDetails` AS `bookcommerce_bcDetails` 
FROM bookcommerce 
WHERE bookcommerce.`bcDetails` LIKE %(bcDetails_1)s
2021-03-25 19:47:11,656 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 46.19s ago] {'bcDetails_1': '"%test%"'}
2021-03-25 19:47:11,663 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Col ('bookcommerce_bcDetails')
2021-03-25 19:47:11,667 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
```

Comment: What are the SQL queries that you see when you add `echo=True` to `create_engine`?

Comment: @rfkortekaas I added those, they do not seem to suggest any particular failure?