# How to search JSON array in MySQL using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have one JSON column in my table. I want to filter by this column using sqlalchemy with Python and MySQL. I've tried in this way, but unsuccessfully.

My column:   `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]`

```
myTable.select().where(func.json_contains(f'"{mycolumn}"', f'"{myArray}"'))
```

Comment: This is pretty similar to this except you would use myTable.c.column instead of myClass.column when not using the orm: [sqlalchemy-json-column-how-to-perform-a-contains-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470239/sqlalchemy-json-column-how-to-perform-a-contains-query)